# Memory corruption on multi threaded client

Tags: c, multithreading, valgrind

I'm coming to you after many days failing at finding and correct a bug.
I'm developping a SMPP multi-threaded client with libsmpp34

After testing it with charges, I've seen that many times :

```
  malloc.c:3091: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004b6165 in raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00000000004773b1 in abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x0000000000483430 in __malloc_assert (assertion=<optimized out>, file=<optimized out>, 
line=<optimized out>, function=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:352
#3  0x000000000048655a in sYSMALLOc (av=<optimized out>, nb=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3088
#4  _int_malloc (av=0x7fffe0000020, bytes=1040) at malloc.c:4762
#5  0x000000000048812f in __libc_malloc (bytes=1040) at malloc.c:3655
#6  0x000000000046684e in build_tlv (dest=0x7ffff37e9750, source=0x7ffff37e9150)
at ../src/smpp34_params.c:107
```

The odd thing is that it's only happen on the test machine which run on Suse and not on the other one on Debian (eglibc)

```
cat /etc/*-release
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64"
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 2
```

With glibc :

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.11.3
```

Other odd thing, on Valgrind, the program work perfectly. I suppose this is caused by the modified env. At the end, Valgrind say that no leaks were found. The only things displayed are conditional jump on uninit values.

For the debugging, I've tried to remove all `free()` but nothing changed.
After that, I've tried to activate mcheck.
Setting MALLOC_CHECK_ prevent the program to crash, which is weird knowing that if `MALLOC_CHECK_=2` must write error message on stdout and `abort()`.
If I `unset MALLOC_CHECK_` the bugs are coming back..
**What can cause this really weird behaviour ?**

I have checked my mallocs and my frees. Nothing seems awkward. Do you have some clues or some help for me ?

Thank you !

EDIT :
Here is a part of the code. Related to my linked list structs.
http://pastebin.com/Wu2KMPLX

As it is discuss, it seems like it can be a rogue pointer. Do you have ideas to track them down ?
And why setting MALLOC_CHECK_ don't trigger the problem anymore ?

Comment: My guess is not that you have a memory leak, but you're overwriting memory with a rogue pointer that is pointing outside the range of its allocated memory.  You'd need to post some source code in order for anyone to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You keep saying "odd", but nothing is "odd" or "weird" if you have a rogue pointer.  This is the world of C, where if you misuse pointers, overwrite memory, etc. then anything can happen, including work sometimes and fail other times.

Comment: Sounds like memory corruption (heap smashing?). Did you try `address sanitizer`?

Comment: @Eric : Ok, i'll try to find out the rogue pointer. Have you some idea and tools to track them down ?

EOF :  Not, yet, I'll try this right now. Thanks.

Comment: Try running valgrind in 'helgrind' mode to see if it catches a data race: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html  Also, you might want to use gdb to examine the variables being checked in the assertion to see specifically what's not right; it might give you some insight to the problem.  The comment in `malloc.c` corresponding to the assertion is: "If not the first time through, we require old_size to be at least MINSIZE and to have prev_inuse set".  In case you want to find out more about the assertion, you can get the source for glibc by cloning `git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBurr for your response.
I've tried hellgrind, it indicate me potential data race. But I don't understand why : http://pastebin.com/2tqpLpCc

I create the msgList when the thread is created, so why a data race can happen ? 

I don't find anything useful in examinating variable being checked in the assertion.

Comment: The helgrind output looks like a false positive to me - glibc's `malloc()` would be thread-safe. glibc 2.11 is from 2009 - maybe the valgrind developers haven't worked to make valgrind/helgrind aware of suspect, but non-bugged, behavior in that library version? (I'm grasping at straws). Another straw to grasp at: maybe see if Address Sanitizer (https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) helps.  I've never used it, so I have no idea whether it's ready for prime-time or might improve on valgrind. Therefore keep in mind that I might be suggesting a fool's errand.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try AddressSanitizer. Do you have any clue about why setting MALLOC_CHECK_ hide the error ?

Comment: No idea. I'm not very familiar with `malloc()` internals.  It looks like turning on malloc checking only makes a couple fundamental changes: 1) pointers are checked to be allocated blocks before actually freeing them (to detect double frees), and 2) a single sentinel byte at the end of an allocation is added and set to a magic number that's based on the block's address to check for writes past the end of the buffer.  Look at `malloc/hooks.c` to see this. Then again, I don't know what the assertion you're hitting is actually complaining about, so I don't know what could really be affecting it.

Comment: Actually, another important difference is that when malloc checking is enabled, the allocation and free functions always serialize on the same mutex - the one in the `main_arena` variable.  Without malloc checking enabled, the allocation and free functions serialize on a per-arena instance mutex. I don't fully understand how arenas are used in the allocator, but I imagine that they try to use different arenas for different threads. So an important difference is that with malloc checking enabled there will be essentially no concurrency in the malloc code.